# $X^T r = 0$ means residual is uncorrelated with $X$?

Tags: regression, correlation, least-squares

In OLS, we have the following

$$
X^Tr = 0
$$
where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ data matrix and $r \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the vector of residuals.

The above equal shows that the column of samples corresponding to the j-th independent variable, where $j \in {1, \ldots, p}$$, is orthogonal to the residual vector.

But does this necessarily imply that the 2 are uncorrelated. Covariance is essentially a centered inner product, but in this case $X$ is not necessarily centered. If it is was centered, then the above result can be used to conclude uncorrelatedness, but if it is not known whether $X$ is centered, then can we still make the assertion of uncorrelatedness?

Comment: I don't think $X^Tr=0$ in itself implies they're uncorrelated. But since you also know that the mean of the residuals is zero, you can show that the covariance is zero. 

\begin{align}
    cov(X_i, r) = 
    E[(X_i - \mu_{X_i})(r)] \\
    = E[X_ir] - \mu_{X_i}E[r] \\
    = \frac{1}{n}\langle X_i, r\rangle - \mu_{X_i}*0 = 0\\
\end{align}

Comment: This derivation chooses a single variable, but there's no loss of generality. Also note that $r$ lies in the nullspace of $X^T$

Comment: @lamanon why don't you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think $X^Tr = 0$ itself is sufficient to show that all the regressors are uncorrelated with the residuals. However, for OLS with an intercept, you know that

$$
\sum_i^n r_i = 0 \\
\therefore E[r_i] = 0 \\
$$

You can then use this information to derive that the covariance is zero between any regressor and the residual, hence correlation is zero, as follows:
\begin{align}
\text{cov}(X_j, r) = E[X_jr] - E[X_j]E[r] && \forall X_j \in \{X_1, \ldots, X_p\}\\
=\frac{1}{n}\langle X_j, r \rangle - E[X_j]*0 \\
= 0 - 0 = 0
\end{align}